# SPCommon.png keeps being deleted from the HIVE SP2013

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sharepoint, deployment, themes, sharepoint-2013

So I made a mistake when developing a SharePoint feature.  The goal was to have a white settings cog [image: white cog]

The way I achieved this originally was by editing SPCommon.png in an image editor and replacing it via the SharePoint Mapped Folder like so: [image]

I then used CSS to move the image in it's frame so the white cog was shown instead of black.  Great it works a treat and worked for months.

I've subsequently learnt this is against Microsoft best practice and rightly so because it all came unstuck when the latest service pack was installed which overwrote the customised image and the feature stopped working.

[10 Best Practices For Building SharePoint Solutions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd458798.aspx#id0090122)

> The 12 hive is a shared Web application space. If you plan on hosting multiple Web apps in the same farm, you need to ensure that your SharePoint solutions do not overwrite existing SharePoint files or files deployed by other solutions in this space.

So I decided that as I didn't need to replace this file anymore and in fact I shouldn't that I should remove it from the solution so that it doesn't get deployed anymore.  Seemed the right step at the time.  In development this was fine, in staging it was fine, the file just doesn't get deployed.  BUT..... in production the file gets deleted from the HIVE and no longer exists!  Crud!

There must be a certain set of conditions which cause this to happen, that's what I hate about SharePoint it is so inconsistent. I haven't worked out yet what the differences are that cause it but not only does it get deleted during a deploy, it seems to keep getting deleted and the Enterprise Admins keep having to replace the file in the file system by copying it back out of the staging farm onto every server in the farm.  This is not good.....

Fortunately I haven't had to admit to them that I caused this problem yet, this is the next confession, because I couldn't prove it although I was very concerned.  Yesterday I deployed our solution into our departments development server, yes CI is on the TODO list too, where-as I usually use my local VM.  Low and behold the file get's deleted on this server during the deploy.  This is good and bad, I now have an environment which is displaying the problem which I have full control over but the bad news is it is my fault.

So the next step is to try and diagnose what in the solution, or lack in the solution is causing this to happen?

I have had to change the way this is derived so as to not replace the file, but I have also learnt that my second attempt is still not right and I should be using the Theme Engine, but that is work to improve for another day once I get this fixed.
[Use SharePoint Online Composed Looks and Theming Engine to Brand spcommon.png](http://ericoverfield.com/use-sharepoint-online-composed-looks-theming-engine-brand-spcommon-png/)

Comment: does the file get deleted randomly or only when you mess around (deploy, retract) with the solution that copied the file to the 15 hive in the first place?

Comment: It does seem to happen randomly even when there hasn't been a deploy.  I wondered if it would happen when a feature was reactivated, but they shouldn't being reactivated.

Comment: I'm not completely sure about the process, but I think files are copied to the hive during the Install-SPSolution and removed during the Uninstall-SPSolution portion.  Since your WSP has a reference to the file in there, it makes sense for it to be deleted during uninstallation, but not randomly. Have you tried removing the file from the WSP, updating the solution, manually replacing the file and seeing if it still gets deleted afterwards?

Comment: Yes, I'd totally agree that would make sense and what you would expect, but I'm not totally convinced that is what happens in action.  I don't ever get to witness the processes that our Enterprise Admins go through, but your right there is a small amount of PowerShell, but I think they do Update-SPSolution.  There wasn't a problem with that until the reference to IMAGES\spcommon.png was removed from the WSP as a reference in the manifests.xml.  Perhaps that's the problem I need to get them to do a full Uninstall-SPSolution before redeploying afresh?

Comment: I just wish it had happened in Staging first which is the whole point of that environment!

Comment: You should ask for a full retract and deploy cycle. Update-SPSolutions does not take in to account changes to the file structure, inclusion or removal.

Comment: and I know how you feel! I recently ran in to a similar situation with things working fine in one place and borked in another more critical situation

Comment: Just thought of a reason why it might seem to be random.  The image might still be missing from one of the WFEs so if the site request that one it might look like it's been deleted again.  I did ask them to replace it on all of them though.